# Javascript/GApps Script - Access Object Property using Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, google-apps-script

I have a object that may have up to thirty one properties, that all need to be checked for values multiple times. So I have created an array that contains the name's of these properties so that instead of having to assign each property to its own variable I can just check the value of this property using a loop in the array.

```
var dates = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth", "thirteenth", "fourteenth", "fifteenth", "sixteenth", "seventeenth", "eighteenth", "nineteenth", "twentieth", "twentyfirst", "twentysecond", "twentythird", "twentyfourth", "twentyfifth", "twentysixth", "twentyseventh", "twentyeighth", "twentyninth", "thirtieth", "thirtyfirst"];

for (var k=3; k<=lastrw; k++){
for (var l = 0; l < 31; l++){
  var mydate = dates[l];
  if (typeof holidayObjects[k-3].mydate != undefined){
    switch (holidayObjects[k-3].mydate){
      case "HD": break;
      case "H": break;
      case "BH": break;
      case "": break;
      case undefined: break;
      default: ss.getSheetByName(mysheet).getRange(k,(l+2)).setValue("");
    }
  }
}
}
```

However this never seems to work, keep in mind that some properties will never be defined for example it could have first defined but third not defined hence the if statement

Is there any reason as to why this shouldnt work, if yes how would I go about fixing this and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `holidayObjects[k-3][mydate]` instead of `holidayObjects[k-3].mydate`

When you use `.mydate`, you're trying to access the property "mydate" where as using `[mydate]` will attempt to access "first", "second", "third", ...